# Copying text content of an element to empty sibling element

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using ElementTree for some times now and there's something that i'm trying without much success. I got a XML file with this king of tree:

```
<root>
   <page>
       <revision>
            <username>Name</>
            <ID>124</>
            <Adress_ip></>
       <revision>
            <username></>
            <ID>125</>
            <Adress_ip>192.168.0.1</>
```

What i'm trying to do it's to put both username and Adress_ip in the same element. More precisely, i'm trying to, whene username is empty, fill it with the text found in Adress_IP. There's always one on other value, never both at the same time in the same  element.

So far, i was trying with some code looking like this. The problem? This script don't want to do it's if sentence, therfore lefting blank all elements without username. Of course, this is not what i was hoping for.

```
for contributor in tree.iter("revision"):
    for username in contributor.findall('username'):
        vide = username.text.find("")
        if username.text == vide:
            for userip in contributor.findall('ip'):
                revision.set('username', userip.text)
        else:        
            revision.set('username', username.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

> This script don't want to do it's if sentence, therfore lefting blank all elements without username.

This bit,

```
vide = username.text.find("")
if username.text == vide: 
    ...
```

does not work; it does not test whether `username` is empty. Just use

```
if username.text == None:
    ...
```

---

> What i'm trying to do it's to put both username and Adress_ip in the same element. More precisely, i'm trying to, whene username is empty, fill it with the text found in Adress_IP. There's always one on other value, never both at the same time in the same element.

Input XML (revisions.xml):

```
<root>
  <page>
    <revision>
      <username>Name</username>
      <ID>124</ID>
      <Adress_ip></Adress_ip>
    </revision>     
    <revision>
      <username></username>
      <ID>125</ID>
      <Adress_ip>192.168.0.1</Adress_ip>
    </revision>     
  </page>
</root>
```

Python program:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("revisions.xml")

for revision in tree.iter("revision"):
    username = revision.find('username')
    Adress_ip = revision.find('Adress_ip')
    if username.text == None:           
        username.text = Adress_ip.text

print ET.tostring(tree.getroot())
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <page>
    <revision>
      <username>Name</username>
      <ID>124</ID>
      <Adress_ip />
    </revision>     
    <revision>
      <username>192.168.0.1</username>
      <ID>125</ID>
      <Adress_ip>192.168.0.1</Adress_ip>
    </revision>     
  </page>
</root>
```